# How to ignore the error No such file directory in the ls command?

Tags: linux, ls

How to ignore the error `No such file directory`?

```
ls /opt/data/config/run_*.config | cut -f1 -d '.' | cut -f2 -d '_' 2>/dev/null
ls: cannot access /opt/data/config/run_*.config: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Put the `2 >/dev/null` redirection after the `ls` command.

Comment: Btw. I don't know what/why you're trying to do, but it looks a bit ramshackle.

Comment: I want to get the values between `run_` and `.` directory `/opt /data/config /`

Comment: This resolved `/opt/data/config/run_*.config 2> / dev / null | cut -f1 -d '.' | cut -f2 -d '_'`

Comment: Thanks, do you see a more performing way of doing this?

Comment: If using `ls`, I'd just use it as `/bin/ls -1`, since it appears you are only interested in the file names; sometimes `ls` is aliased to `ls -la` or whatever.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about the unix command-line tool `ls`, not about programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing the following:

```
ls <something> | cut <some_cut> | cut <some_other_cut> 2>/dev/null
```

This will do the `ls`, the first and the second `cut`, and when an error is generated at the second `cut`, it will be sent to the `null` device (which means it will be removed).

If you want to remove the error message from any command, you need to put it immediately after the corresponding command, so you get three cases:

```
Case 1: ls <something> | cut <some_cut> | cut <some_other_cut> 2>/dev/null
Case 2: ls <something> 2>/dev/null | cut <some_cut> | cut <some_other_cut>
Case 3: ls <something> 2>/dev/null | cut <some_cut> 2>/dev/null | cut <some_other_cut> 2>/dev/null
```

Case 1 is the situation you're having now.
Case 2 and 3 are possible solutions: case 2 only removes error messages from the `ls` command, while case 3 removes error messages from every command.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and help